# rails add custom responder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, pdf-generation

i have added a ps-mimetype and can render app/views/mycontroller/show.ps.erb templates to deliver postscript by adding

```
Mime::Type.register "application/postscript", :ps
```

to config/initializers/mime_types.rb - this works fine with calling in the controller

```
respond_to :html, :ps, :pdf
def show
  @item = Item.find(1)
  respond_with(@item)
```

now i just want to have a custom responder which takes the same app/views/mycontroller/show.ps.erb template, render it and pipe the result through ghostscripts ps2pdf. where do i have to put the to_pdf responder? how can i reuse the whole rendering from the ps-mimetype?